# Using chinese character in drupal_mail_send() generates unreadable character

Tags: 6

I am using code similar to the following one.

```
$message = array(
  'id' => 'named_fund',
  'to' => $email,
  'subject' => '恭喜您！',
  'body' => '恭喜！',
  'headers' => array('From' => 'Company Name <example@example.com>', 'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset="utf-8";'),
);

drupal_mail_send($message);
```

When I use Chinese characters for the "From" header, I get strange characters. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
drupal_mail_send(utf8_encode($message));
```

As Oswald implied, this is a character encoding issue.

If any data is coming from, or going to be stored in, the database, also make sure your database character encoding is utf8_general_ci.

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured drupal to use an SMTP library (by setting the `smtp_library` drupal variable), you are responsible for properly encoding the headers (unless the library does that for you).

If you did not configure drupal to use an SMTP library, make sure that the source code of the module is encoded in UTF 8.